# I didn't understand how this inequality simplified on Tom Apostol's Calculus

Tags: inequality

on page 7 of the Tom Apostol's Calculus there is a inequality that

$$\frac{b^3}{3} - \frac{b^3}{n}<A<\frac{b^3}{3} + \frac{b^3}{n}$$

and then Apostol says:

*for every integer*

$$n\ge1$$ *now there are only three possiblities:*
$$A>\frac{b^3}{3}$$$$A<\frac{b^3}{3}$$$$A=\frac{b^3}{3}$$

I didn't understand how Apostol did make this inference, can anyone explain me this ? The relevant page is there [page 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk67v.png)

Comment: Real numbers are a totally ordered set. This means that for every two numbers $a,b$, either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$. If you separate $\leq$ into "$=$ or $<$", then the statement is: For every two numbers $a,b$, either $a<b$ or $a=b$ or $a>b$. In particular, this is true for $A$ and $\frac{b^3}{3}$, for any $A$ and $b$.

Comment: @Alessandro Thank you for your explanation, i think i was too focused on the first given equation that i didn't notice this obvious thing.